# как обратиться к функциям из ctx.canvas.addEventListener(){} лежащим вне него

Tags: javascript

Никак не могу понять как обратится к функциям класса Game - reset() и start() 
Вот моя ситуация вкратце:

У нас есть класс

```
Game {
    Конструктор класса{
      данные
}
reset(){
      обновляем данные 
}
start(){
      Подготовка данных 
}
update(deltaTime){
}
draw(ctx){

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 250, 0, 1)";
      ctx.fillRect(280, 350, 150, 80);

      ctx.font = '40pt Kremlin Pro Web';
      ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
      ctx.fillText('Start', 345, 415);

      function isInside(pos, rect){
            return pos.x > rect.x &&
                   pos.x < rect.x+rect.width && 
                   pos.y < rect.y+rect.height && 
                   pos.y > rect.y
      }

      function getMousePos(ctx, event) {
        var rect = ctx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: event.clientX - rect.left,
          y: event.clientY - rect.top
        };
      }


      var rect = {
        x: 280,
        y: 350,
        width: 50,
        height: 80
      };

      ctx.canvas.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
          var mousePos = getMousePos(ctx, evt);
          if (isInside(mousePos,rect)) {
            this.reset();  ?????
            this.start();  ?????

          }
      }, false);
```

→ КАК ОБРАТИТЬСЯ К ФУНКЦИЯМ КЛАССА GAME, которые были объявлены выше? RESET() & START()?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ctx.canvas.addEventListener("click", evt => {
      var mousePos = getMousePos(ctx, evt);
      if (isInside(mousePos, rect)) {
        this.reset();
        this.start();
      }
  }, false);
```

Comment: Спасибо!  Не получалось как раз из-за меняющегося значения this! 

А стрелочная функция его значит не меняет

Comment: @LilijaSternberg Совершенно верно. Пожалуйста. Успехов.